# After updating WordPress: Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).isotope is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-isotope

I wonder if someone could take a look and help me with this. On one WordPress page there's jQuery error which can be seen in console.  I guess it's after WordPress core update. Here is the [link](https://multimed.pl/lekarze/dr-n-med-artur-barczyk/)

Update:
Error 1: Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).stick_in_parent is not a function
Error 2: Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).isotope is not a function

Comment: You need to add the console error in your question; don't make people go to a link.

Comment: @markratledge done

Comment: Those are very common errors having to do with unloaded and out-of-date libraries; search this site for similar questions with accepted answers.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is because isotope.js has not been called, place this in your child theme:

```
function ngaire_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script('isotope', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/path-to-isotope/isotope.pkgd.min.js', false, false, true);
}
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ngaire_scripts' );
```

Where path-to-isotope is where you are placing your isotope.js file.

Comment: @rhyssclay Thanks a lot. But I'm getting error on add_action line.

Comment: Sorry - was missing the closing bracket in the function. Try again now.

Comment: @rhyssclay It's ok now. It should go into header or footer?